# copy() function error

Tags: php

Here is my input field..

```
<input type="file" name="upload_file[]" value="" id=" "/>

$attach = $_FILES["upload_file[]"]["name"];
$sql = "insert into uploadfile(CAT_ID, SUB_CAT_ID, TAG, DESCRIPTION, UF_NAME, UF_NAME1 , GENRE) values('".$category."','".$subcategory."','".$tag."','".$optionaldescription."','".$attach."','".$attach."','".$genre."')";
copy($_FILES['upload_file[]']['tmp_name'], "upload/".$_FILES['upload_file']['name']);
mysql_query($sql);

Warning: copy() [function.copy]: Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 48
```

Comment: @John: get some sleep - it help in such situations :-)

Comment: is there  a need to include the badly formatted SQL (might not escaped properly)?

Comment: @Michal Srajer: yes Mike... i rely on you guys when nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP automatically converts HTML form elements that end in `[]` to arrays, therefore, access the `0`nt element of the array:

```
$attach = $_FILES["upload_file"][0]["name"];
$sql = "insert into uploadfile(CAT_ID, SUB_CAT_ID, TAG, DESCRIPTION, UF_NAME, UF_NAME1 , GENRE) values('".$category."','".$subcategory."','".$tag."','".$optionaldescription."','".$attach."','".$attach."','".$genre."')";
copy($_FILES['upload_file'][0]['tmp_name'], "upload/".$_FILES['upload_file'][0]['name']);
mysql_query($sql);
```

In addition, you should be using [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) in place of [`copy()`](http://php.net/copy).

Answer (score 2):

There is a dedicated function for that. Please throw out your `copy` code and use [move_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

The error is caused by your attempt to access `$_FILES['uploaded_file[]']`, which isn't going to exist. PHP will interpret post/get variables ending with `[]` as arrays; the file you're interested in is probably sitting at `$_FILES['uploaded_file'][0]`.

Please learn to debug your simple PHP applications. Try `var_dump($_FILES)` to start, it will tell you exactly what is in the `$_FILES` array.

Answer (score 1):

use

`$_FILES['upload_file'][0]['tmp_name']`

yours one does not work because [] is an array